# If we live in a false vacuum, why do cosmologists claim we’d end in a Big Crunch after the vacuum decays?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, vacuum

Suppose we live in a metastable false vacuum and it decays into a true vacuum in an ever expanding bubble. In the thin-wall approximation, spacetime is partitioned into a region with a false vacuum and a bubble with the true vacuum, with the domain wall as the boundary between both of them. As seen from outside the bubble, the domain wall expands indefinitely for an infinite proper time.

Some cosmologists claim that the interior of the bubble will end in a Big Crunch singularity. However, if that were the case, then since the domain wall is the boundary of the bubble, it would also terminate at a singularity after a finite proper time. This is a contradiction.

So why are such claims made in the literature?

Comment: Can you link to some literature which makes these claims?